# Flutter Create Spawns app That Contains Unexpected Folders and Files

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-create

About a week ago, I created a new flutter project using:

```
flutter create -t app my_app
```

But when I opened the resulting project in the IDE, I was surprised to find the project has some key differences compared to what I'm used to:

- there is a folder inside the lib folder, "src"
- the main.dart does not contain the usual "counter app" and looks like this:

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'src/app.dart';
import 'src/settings/settings_controller.dart';
import 'src/settings/settings_service.dart';

void main() async {
  // Set up the SettingsController, which will glue user settings to multiple
  // Flutter Widgets.
  final settingsController = SettingsController(SettingsService());

  // Load the user's preferred theme while the splash screen is displayed.
  // This prevents a sudden theme change when the app is first displayed.
  await settingsController.loadSettings();

  // Run the app and pass in the SettingsController. The app listens to the
  // SettingsController for changes, then passes it further down to the
  // SettingsView.
  runApp(MyApp(settingsController: settingsController));
}
```

I tried creating other new projects and I verified it also happened when using "flutter create -t skeleton."

Now, after a week, it seems to have gone back to the old behavior.

Does anyone know the explanation for this?

Comment: what flutter version are you using? There are templates available at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably ran the command

```bash
flutter create -t skeleton my_app
```

Then that's exactly what your project will look like, as you described. This can be seen [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/skeleton/lib).

If you run

```bash
flutter create -t app my_app
```

or

```dart
flutter create my_app
```

then a default counter application must be created, as [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/app/lib)

There may have been an undiscovered error. But to do this, you need to know the exact version of flutter you were using at the time, and the 100% command you entered. That's how it could be repeated. Is everything all right now?

Answer (score 0):

At first let me describe what is  `flutter create -t skeleton`:

For many years Flutter has provided the basic `Counter App` each time you created a new project.
While that example provides a nice introduction to the foundational concepts of `StatefulWidget` and basic font/asset management, it does not really resemble the structure of a `complete app`.
This has left developers without guidance for anything beyond a basic single page app.

To fix this issue the Flutter team have been hard at work on a new template with the stated goals:

Make it easier for developers to continue their learning journey beyond the Counter app.Co-exist with the original Counter app template.It is not a replacement.

The new template was merged into master in June 2021, and you can create it with this command:

`flutter create -t skeleton your_project_name`

---

#### Now what happened to you ?

I guess your name of project is `my_app` .
And this code created by run `flutter create -t skeleton my_app` and very similar to `flutter create -t app my_app` statement .